# Building Android SDK: Only one Android target being created

Tags: android, android-emulator, makefile

Edit: I know I can download the SDK easily, but I specifically want to build everything myself. I'm trying to understand the build process more.

I used repo to download the AOSP source. Multiple places guide me to build the SDK as follows:

```
$ cd $AOSP_ROOT 
$ . build/envsetup.sh
$ lunch sdk-eng
$ make sdk
```

This works perfectly, I get a zip file with the SDK and the emulator works. However, the only Android target that is generated is the latest one e.g.

```
$ cd $SDK_ROOT/platforms
$ ls
android-4.0.4.0.4.0.4
```

is all I see. How can I get the other Android targets? Do I have to use repo to switch the branch of Android that I'm on, build the *entire* SDK and just copy out the appropriate target files? Is there some simpler way, like a different make target that would achieve this? Can I request that the SDK be built and that all targets be available? Should I just download a non-locally-compiled SDK and copy the targets to my SDK_ROOT/platforms?

Comment: I am not sure what your end goal is, but if you download Eclipse Indigo SR2, and install ADT (Android Development Tools) it will let you easily download all of the SDK's right from within Eclipse.

Comment: Yes that's simple, but I want to build SDK+all targets myself. This is part of a larger problem where I'm learning more about the Android build system. It's easy to build the SDK, but the lack of Android targets obviously limits the effectiveness. I'm trying to figure out what I need to modify in my make procedure so I get all targets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use repo tool to switch to the appropriate branch and build your SDK for this branch. I do not think that it is possible to build SDK for all branches simultaneously.

Comment: I'm seeing the same - thanks! I suppose a build script might be useful here :-/